# cassandra copy makes empty string null on reimport

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

I use `COPY` command to take a copy of data. `COPY` looks more simple than sstables. But it looks like it can't import empty string. Columns which are empty in original table are null in imported. Steps to reproduce below.

```
CREATE TABLE empty_example (id bigint PRIMARY KEY, empty_column text, null_column text);
INSERT INTO empty_example (id, empty_column) VALUES ( 1, '');
SELECT * from empty_example ;
 id | empty_column | null_column
----+--------------+-------------
  1 |              |        null
COPY empty_example TO 'empty_example.csv';
TRUNCATE empty_example ;
COPY empty_example FROM  'empty_example.csv';
SELECT * from empty_example ;
 id | empty_column | null_column
----+--------------+-------------
  1 |         null |        null
```

I tried to play with `WITH` options but couldn't solve the issue.
Is it possible to preserve null/empty string distinction with `COPY`?

Answer (score 3):

Which version of Cassandra are you using ? Since Cassandra 3.4, COPY commands has a bunch of options to handle empty or null strings:

```
cqlsh:system_schema> help COPY

        COPY [cqlsh only]

          COPY x FROM: Imports CSV data into a Cassandra table
          COPY x TO: Exports data from a Cassandra table in CSV format.

        COPY <table_name> [ ( column [, ...] ) ]
             FROM ( '<file_pattern_1, file_pattern_2, ... file_pattern_n>' | STDIN )
             [ WITH <option>='value' [AND ...] ];

        File patterns are either file names or valid python glob expressions, e.g. *.csv or folder/*.csv.

        COPY <table_name> [ ( column [, ...] ) ]
             TO ( '<filename>' | STDOUT )
             [ WITH <option>='value' [AND ...] ];

        Available common COPY options and defaults:

          DELIMITER=','           - character that appears between records
          QUOTE='"'               - quoting character to be used to quote fields
          ESCAPE='\'              - character to appear before the QUOTE char when quoted
          HEADER=false            - whether to ignore the first line
          NULL=''                 - string that represents a null value
```

As you can see, by default the option **NULL=''** means that empty string is treated as **null** value. To change this behavior, set **NULL='null'** or whatever character you want for null value ...

Comment: What if it is date column